# JPA, avoiding loading entities every time association is traversed

Tags: java, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I have a Customer class defined like this:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", orphanRemoval = true, FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name = "name")
    private Map<String, Operation> operationMap = new HashMap<String, Operation>();
```

My GUI application retrieves this customer through an EJB and then updates the customer and/or its operations. The problem is that whenever the `operationMap` collection is traversed, new proxies of `Operation` entities are created and this creates a problem for GUI components. Some are still bound to old proxies, while some are bound to new proxies.

How do you propose to solve this problem? Try to traverse the `operationMap` only once? Is there a way to limit creation of new proxies somehow?

I'm using EclipseLink JPA (Glassfish AS).

Comment: I am far from expert with JPA, but isn't it supposed that only a copy of any entity exists (if it is loaded several times from several threads, the ORM cache should return the same object)?

Comment: Thanks, you in fact pointed me to the right way. A method was called by accident that fetched `Customer` entity even after initial page load, thus every time creating new detached `Customer` entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a bug in my managed bean. A method was called by accident that fetched Customer entity even after initial page load, thus every time creating new detached `Customer` entities.